# Passing macro variable to function for interpolation

Tags: macros, julia, metaprogramming, hygiene

I'm trying to write a macro that evaluates an expression and then compares it with a few values.
I have reduce the problem to a smaller example for this post.

```
macro small_bad(item)
    quote
        $(use_val(esc(item)))
    end
end

function use_val(val)
    quote
        if $val == 1
            1
        elseif $val == 2
            2
        else
            -1
        end
    end
end
```

Because I don't want to evaluate the expr more than once, I want to save it in a variable.
So I tried this:

```
macro small_good(item)
    quote
        begin
            val = $(esc(item))
            $(begin
                  use_val(val)
              end)
        end
    end
end
```

But then I get that `val` is undefined in the interpolation in `@small_good`.

I also tried passing `use_val(:val)` but this also fails because the macro system will rename
`val` to something else.

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:**
Given the first answer I tried this in my actual code

```
macro match(item, arms)
    var = gensym(:var)
    quote
        let $var = $(esc(item))
            $(begin
                code = :nothing
                for e in reverse(filter((e) -> e isa Expr, arms.args))
                    code = make_match(var, e, code)
                end
                code
            end)
        end
    end
end
```

and got `UndefVarError: ##var#253 not defined`

[gist with the full code here](https://gist.github.com/mendess/fbb980026431e4d07a9cf30ea2daea25)

*Disclaimer: I know the `@match` macro is already implemented in the Match.jl package, I'm reimplementing a subset of it as a learning exercise*

**EDIT 2:**

I figured it out. After using François Févotte's suggestion I now had to change my real version of `use_val` which was actually doing `$(esc(val))` instead of `$val`.

Mistake on my part for not including that detail. Will update the gist to reflect this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you want, this should work:

```
macro small(item)
    var = gensym(:var)
    quote
        let $var = $(esc(item))
            $(use_val(var))
        end
    end
end

function use_val(val)
    quote
        if $val == 1
            1
        elseif $val == 2
            2
        else
            -1
        end
    end
end
```

It expands to something like:

```
julia> using MacroTools
julia> MacroTools.@expand @small myexpr
quote
    let octopus = myexpr
        begin
            if octopus == 1
                1
            elseif octopus == 2
                2
            else
                -1
            end
        end
    end
end
```

and has issues with neither hygiene nor multiple evaluations:

```
# Testing in a local scope introduced by `let`
# is a good way to check for hygiene issues
julia> let arg = [1]
           @small pop!(arg)
       end
1
```

---

Now I'm guessing a lot of the substance of your original problem has been lost during the MWE creation process, because all this is essentially equivalent to:

```
julia> function small(val)
           if val == 1
               1
           elseif val == 2
               2
           else
               -1
           end
       end
small (generic function with 1 method)

julia> let args = [1]
           small(pop!(args))
       end
1
```

Comment: I couldn't quite make it work. I'll update the post with what I tried to do using you suggestion, possibly bringing more relevant context.